# performance of internationalized html templates

Tags: python, internationalization, flask, template-engine, jinja2

I'm writing a web application using Python and the Flask microframework. The application will support several languages, and I'm now trying to decide how to write i18n enabled html templates. My template engine is Jinja2 (though it is early enough in my project that I can switch to something else if necessary).

Let me start by showing an example portion of a template with gettext tags:

```
{% if error %}<div class="error">{{ _(error) }}</div>{% endif %}
<h1>{{ _("Hello, World!") }}</h1>
```

In this template there are two kinds of strings that the application will need to know how to  translate:

1. dynamic strings that in the context of the template will only be known at runtime (the `error` string)
2. static strings that are known at any time (the `"Hello, World!"` string)

The first case is easy to handle. The string is passed to the gettext engine at runtime to obtain the translated version. No issues there.

While the second case can be handled in the same way, my impression is that there's got to be a more efficient way to handle these static strings. None of the documentation I read for gettext, Babel or Jinja2 mention anything about optimizing the translation of static strings that will have to be searched and located every time the template needs to be rendered.

An approach that I think makes a lot of sense is to pre-render each template into a set of language specific sub-templates, where each sub-template has the static strings resolved, leaving only the dynamic text sections for gettext to handle at runtime.

So, for example, if I wanted to support English and Spanish, my template above would be processed offline by some tool that will generate two sub-templates that will get written to a template cache:

template-en.html:

```
{% if error %}<div class="error">{{ _(error) }}</div>{% endif %}
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
```

template-es.html:

```
{% if error %}<div class="error">{{ _(error) }}</div>{% endif %}
<h1>¡Hola, Mundo!</h1>
```

Then at runtime the template engine needs to check if a specific sub-template for the requested locale is available in the cache, and if one is found then rendering will be much faster.

Are there any frameworks, tools, template engines, etc. that implement something like this?

Or are there any other ways to avoid the overhead of searching the translation database for the same little snippets of text over and over again?

Answer (score 1):

Have you measured the impact of such an "optimization" on the whole request-response cycle? I'd be very surprised if you would see any meaningful speedups, especially when using a template language that is already known to be pretty darn fast, like Jinja2.

As a general rule: never optimize before having measured the potential gains of the optimization. Intuition is oftentimes completely wrong in this area. This is especially true when an optimization introduces complication in code, development or deployment - always measure if it is worth the hassle.

You'd probably have more success looking into optimizing database queries or caching of expensive operations (a `dict` lookup, which `gettext` basically is, is not expensive at all).

Comment: I totally agree that some things are not worth optimizing, but this seems like something that could be done transparently without really adding any complication. In case you are interested, my measurements tell me that a small template without gettext renders in about 60% of the time it takes the gettext enabled equivalent. The test template has eight translations and another eight unrelated replacements that do not need to get translated. And I haven't measured memory usage yet, but I bet there is a difference there as well.

Comment: I don't deny that there is a possible speedup when only measuring the rendering of the template - especially if the template is a lot of gettext calls and nothing else. What I doubt is that you'll be able to measure real speedups when rendering the template in the full request-respone cycle. If anything non-trivial happens there (e.g. some DB queries or other kind of I/O), template rendering basically vanishes. (case in point: http://www.codeirony.com/?p=9)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. You should never I18Nize variables (your first type), ***only*** static text (your second type). You need to I18Nize the strings that could be used in `error`, not the variable itself.

And optimization should be done at the message catalog (gettext) level, not in your code.

Comment: *Optimization should be done at the message catalog level, not in your code*. Really? It is hard to optimize a hundred little searches, if I also had the option to prerender the whole thing offline. What is the benefit of doing the translation at runtime (as optimized as it may be) when I can potentially do the work just once and generate new templates that have all the texts solved to each language?

Comment: Certainly you can do that, but that's not "optimization", that's "prerendering".